Access denied by service policy in ejabberd
I am trying register new user in my xmpp server with help of node.js.
below is the code:
import { client, xml } from '@xmpp/client';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { exec as execCallback } from 'child_process';
import { promisify } from 'util';
const exec = promisify(execCallback);

@Injectable()
export class XmppService {
  private xmppClient: any;
  private pendingIQs: Map<string, Function>;

  constructor() {
    this.pendingIQs = new Map();
    this.initializeClient();
  }

  private initializeClient() {
    this.xmppClient = client({
      service: 'wss://abc.com:5443/ws/rest/register', // WebSocket URL
      domain: 'abc.com',                 // ejabberd domain
      username: 'admin',                                    // Admin username
      password: 'abc@123',                                 // Admin password
    });

    this.xmppClient.on('error', (err: any) => {
      console.error('❌ XMPP Error:', err);
    });

    this.xmppClient.on('offline', () => {
      console.log('❌ XMPP Client is offline');
    });

    this.xmppClient.on('stanza', (stanza: any) => {
      console.log(' Incoming stanza:', stanza.toString());

      if (stanza.is('iq')) {
        const id = stanza.attrs.id;
        const resolve = this.pendingIQs.get(id);
        if (resolve) {
          resolve(stanza);
          this.pendingIQs.delete(id);
        }
      }
    });

    this.xmppClient.on('online', async (address: any) => {
      console.log('✅ XMPP Client is online as', address.toString());
    });

    this.xmppClient.start().catch((err: any) => {
      console.error('❌ Failed to start XMPP Client:', err);
      // Retry logic with delay
      setTimeout(() => this.initializeClient(), 60000); // Wait for 1 minute before retrying
    });
  }

  async addUser(adduserDto: any) {
    console.log("=========AdduserDTO==============", adduserDto);
    try {
      console.log(` Attempting to add user ${adduserDto.username}...`);
      const id = 'register1';
      const iq = xml(
        'iq',
        { type: 'set', id },
        xml('query', { xmlns: 'jabber:iq:register' },
          xml('username', {}, adduserDto.username),
          xml('password', {}, adduserDto.password)
        )
      );

      const responsePromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.pendingIQs.set(id, resolve);
      });

      await this.xmppClient.send(iq);

      const response = await responsePromise;
      console.log(`✅ User ${adduserDto.username} added successfully.`);
      if (typeof response === 'object' && response !== null && 'toString' in response) {
        console.log(' Response:', response.toString());
      } else {
        console.log('⚠️ Response is not in the expected format:', response);
      }

      console.log(response);
      console.log("responseeeeeeeee");
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error('❌ Error adding user:', error);
      if (error.condition === 'policy-violation' && error.text.includes('Too many failed authentications')) {
        console.log('⚠️ Too many failed authentications. Please wait before trying again.');
        // Optionally, add retry logic here if needed
      }
    }
  }
}

And receive below error:
Response: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" xml:lang="en" to="admin@abc.com/123490873350233766351458" from="admin@abc.com" type="error" id="register1"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:register"><username>newuser1</username><password>newuser1@123</password></query><error type="auth"><forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xml:lang="en" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">Access denied by service policy</text></error></iq>

Below is the ejabberd.yml file:
###
###              ejabberd configuration file
###

default_db: sql
sql_type: pgsql
sql_server: "localhost"
sql_database: "ejabberd"
sql_username: "ejabberd"
sql_password: "abc@1kceci"
sql_port: 5432

hosts:
  - abc.com

loglevel: 5

certfiles:
  - /opt/ejabberd/conf/certs/server.pem
  - /opt/ejabberd/conf/certs/muc.abc.com
  - /opt/ejabberd/conf/certs/proxy.abc.com
  - /opt/ejabberd/conf/certs/pubsub.abc.com
  - /opt/ejabberd/conf/certs/upload.abc.com 

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5223
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    tls: true
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
    shaper: s2s_shaper
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /api: mod_http_api
      /bosh: mod_bosh
      /captcha: ejabberd_captcha
      /upload: mod_http_upload
      /ws: ejabberd_http_ws
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /.well-known/acme-challenge: ejabberd_acme
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  admin:
    user:
      - admin
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      
access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    deny: loopback
    allow: all
  register:
    allow: all  # Allow registration for all users and connections (including s2s)

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          - acl: all
          - acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            - acl: all
            - acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number

shaper:
  normal:
    rate: 3000
    burst_size: 20000
  fast: 100000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
    custom_headers:
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://@HOST@"
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS"
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: always
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    host: muc.abc.com
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      mam: true
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ip_access: trusted_network  # Ensure trusted network is used for registration
    access: register  # Use the newly defined access rule
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_stun_disco: {}
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false

### Local Variables:
### mode: yaml
### End:
### vim: set filetype=yaml tabstop=8

below are received in ejabberd.log:
2024-07-16 07:44:51.618168+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_router:do_route/1:384 Route:
#iq{id = <<"register1">>,type = set,lang = <<"en">>,
    from =
        #jid{
            user = <<"admin">>,server = <<"abc.com">>,
            resource = <<"54781444652829145323347">>,luser = <<"admin">>,
            lserver = <<"abc.com">>,
            lresource = <<"54781444652829145323347">>},
    to =
        #jid{
            user = <<"admin">>,server = <<"abc.com">>,
            resource = <<>>,luser = <<"admin">>,
            lserver = <<"abc.com">>,lresource = <<>>},
    sub_els =
        [#xmlel{
             name = <<"query">>,
             attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:iq:register">>}],
             children =
                 [#xmlel{
                      name = <<"username">>,attrs = [],
                      children = [{xmlcdata,<<"riddhi">>}]},
                  #xmlel{
                      name = <<"password">>,attrs = [],
                      children = [{xmlcdata,<<"riddhi123">>}]}]}],
    meta = #{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,65535,38529,27643}}}
2024-07-16 07:44:51.620155+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_local:route/1:74 Local route:
#iq{id = <<"register1">>,type = set,lang = <<"en">>,
    from =
        #jid{
            user = <<"admin">>,server = <<"abc.com">>,
            resource = <<"54781444652829145323347">>,luser = <<"admin">>,
            lserver = <<"abc.com">>,
            lresource = <<"54781444652829145323347">>},
    to =
        #jid{
            user = <<"admin">>,server = <<"abc.com">>,
            resource = <<>>,luser = <<"admin">>,
            lserver = <<"abc.com">>,lresource = <<>>},
    sub_els =
        [#xmlel{
             name = <<"query">>,
             attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:iq:register">>}],
             children =
                 [#xmlel{
                      name = <<"username">>,attrs = [],
                      children = [{xmlcdata,<<"riddhi">>}]},
                  #xmlel{
                      name = <<"password">>,attrs = [],
                      children = [{xmlcdata,<<"riddhi123">>}]}]}],
    meta = #{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,65535,38529,27643}}}
2024-07-16 07:44:51.621726+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook sm_receive_packet: mod_mam:sm_receive_packet/1
2024-07-16 07:44:51.622826+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_sm:do_route/1:712 Processing IQ to bare JID:
#iq{id = <<"register1">>,type = set,lang = <<"en">>,
    from =
        #jid{
            user = <<"admin">>,server = <<"abc.com">>,
            resource = <<"54781444652829145323347">>,luser = <<"admin">>,
            lserver = <<"abc.com">>,
            lresource = <<"54781444652829145323347">>},
    to =
        #jid{
            user = <<"admin">>,server = <<"abc.com">>,
            resource = <<>>,luser = <<"admin">>,
            lserver = <<"abc.com">>,lresource = <<>>},
    sub_els =
        [#xmlel{
             name = <<"query">>,
             attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:iq:register">>}],
             children =
                 [#xmlel{
                      name = <<"username">>,attrs = [],
                      children = [{xmlcdata,<<"riddhi">>}]},
                  #xmlel{
                      name = <<"password">>,attrs = [],
                      children = [{xmlcdata,<<"riddhi123">>}]}]}],
    meta = #{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,65535,38529,27643}}}
2024-07-16 07:44:51.624464+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_router:do_route/1:384 Route:
#iq{id = <<"register1">>,type = error,lang = <<"en">>,
    from =
        #jid{
            user = <<"admin">>,server = <<"abc.com">>,
            resource = <<>>,luser = <<"admin">>,
            lserver = <<"abc.com">>,lresource = <<>>},
    to =
        #jid{
            user = <<"admin">>,server = <<"abc.com">>,
            resource = <<"54781444652829145323347">>,luser = <<"admin">>,
            lserver = <<"abc.com">>,
            lresource = <<"54781444652829145323347">>},
    sub_els =
        [#register{
             registered = false,remove = false,instructions = undefined,
             username = <<"riddhi">>,nick = undefined,
             password = <<"riddhi123">>,name = undefined,first = undefined,
             last = undefined,email = undefined,address = undefined,
             city = undefined,state = undefined,zip = undefined,
             phone = undefined,url = undefined,date = undefined,
             misc = undefined,text = undefined,key = undefined,
             xdata = undefined,sub_els = []},
         #stanza_error{
             type = auth,by = undefined,reason = forbidden,
             text =
                 [#text{
                      lang = <<"en">>,
                      data = <<"Access denied by service policy">>}],
             sub_els = []}],
    meta = #{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,65535,38529,27643}}}
2024-07-16 07:44:51.625532+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_local:route/1:74 Local route:
#iq{id = <<"register1">>,type = error,lang = <<"en">>,
    from =
        #jid{
            user = <<"admin">>,server = <<"abc.com">>,
            resource = <<>>,luser = <<"admin">>,
            lserver = <<"abc.com">>,lresource = <<>>},
    to =
        #jid{
            user = <<"admin">>,server = <<"abc.com">>,
            resource = <<"54781444652829145323347">>,luser = <<"admin">>,
            lserver = <<"abc.com">>,
            lresource = <<"54781444652829145323347">>},
    sub_els =
        [#register{
             registered = false,remove = false,instructions = undefined,
             username = <<"riddhi">>,nick = undefined,
             password = <<"riddhi123">>,name = undefined,first = undefined,
             last = undefined,email = undefined,address = undefined,
             city = undefined,state = undefined,zip = undefined,
             phone = undefined,url = undefined,date = undefined,
             misc = undefined,text = undefined,key = undefined,
             xdata = undefined,sub_els = []},
         #stanza_error{
             type = auth,by = undefined,reason = forbidden,
             text =
                 [#text{
                      lang = <<"en">>,
                      data = <<"Access denied by service policy">>}],
             sub_els = []}],
    meta = #{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,65535,38529,27643}}}
2024-07-16 07:44:51.626621+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook sm_receive_packet: mod_mam:sm_receive_packet/1
2024-07-16 07:44:51.627363+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_sm:do_route/1:719 Processing packet to full JID:
#iq{id = <<"register1">>,type = error,lang = <<"en">>,
    from =
        #jid{
            user = <<"admin">>,server = <<"abc.com">>,
            resource = <<>>,luser = <<"admin">>,
            lserver = <<"abc.com">>,lresource = <<>>},
    to =
        #jid{
            user = <<"admin">>,server = <<"abc.com">>,
            resource = <<"54781444652829145323347">>,luser = <<"admin">>,
            lserver = <<"abc.com">>,
            lresource = <<"54781444652829145323347">>},
    sub_els =
        [#register{
             registered = false,remove = false,instructions = undefined,
             username = <<"riddhi">>,nick = undefined,
             password = <<"riddhi123">>,name = undefined,first = undefined,
             last = undefined,email = undefined,address = undefined,
             city = undefined,state = undefined,zip = undefined,
             phone = undefined,url = undefined,date = undefined,
             misc = undefined,text = undefined,key = undefined,
             xdata = undefined,sub_els = []},
         #stanza_error{
             type = auth,by = undefined,reason = forbidden,
             text =
                 [#text{
                      lang = <<"en">>,
                      data = <<"Access denied by service policy">>}],
             sub_els = []}],
    meta = #{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,65535,38529,27643}}}
2024-07-16 07:44:51.628581+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_sm:do_route/1:741 Sending to process <0.1756.0>:
#iq{id = <<"register1">>,type = error,lang = <<"en">>,
    from =
        #jid{
            user = <<"admin">>,server = <<"abc.com">>,
            resource = <<>>,luser = <<"admin">>,
            lserver = <<"abc.com">>,lresource = <<>>},
    to =
        #jid{
            user = <<"admin">>,server = <<"abc.com">>,
            resource = <<"54781444652829145323347">>,luser = <<"admin">>,
            lserver = <<"abc.com">>,
            lresource = <<"54781444652829145323347">>},
    sub_els =
        [#register{
             registered = false,remove = false,instructions = undefined,
             username = <<"riddhi">>,nick = undefined,
             password = <<"riddhi123">>,name = undefined,first = undefined,
             last = undefined,email = undefined,address = undefined,
             city = undefined,state = undefined,zip = undefined,
             phone = undefined,url = undefined,date = undefined,
             misc = undefined,text = undefined,key = undefined,
             xdata = undefined,sub_els = []},
         #stanza_error{
             type = auth,by = undefined,reason = forbidden,
             text =
                 [#text{
                      lang = <<"en">>,
                      data = <<"Access denied by service policy">>}],
             sub_els = []}],
    meta = #{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,65535,38529,27643}}}
2024-07-16 07:44:51.629935+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook c2s_handle_info: ejabberd_sm:c2s_handle_info/2
2024-07-16 07:44:51.630587+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook c2s_handle_info: mod_offline:c2s_handle_info/2
2024-07-16 07:44:51.631197+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook c2s_handle_info: mod_pubsub:c2s_handle_info/2
2024-07-16 07:44:51.631801+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook c2s_handle_info: mod_push_keepalive:c2s_handle_info/2
2024-07-16 07:44:51.632564+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook c2s_handle_info: mod_stream_mgmt:c2s_handle_info/2
2024-07-16 07:44:51.633167+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook c2s_handle_info: ejabberd_c2s:process_info/2
2024-07-16 07:44:51.633692+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook privacy_check_packet: mod_last:privacy_check_packet/4
2024-07-16 07:44:51.634088+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook privacy_check_packet: mod_privacy:check_packet/4
2024-07-16 07:44:51.634477+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook user_receive_packet: mod_caps:user_receive_packet/1
2024-07-16 07:44:51.635019+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook user_receive_packet: mod_mam:user_receive_packet/1
2024-07-16 07:44:51.635634+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook user_receive_packet: mod_carboncopy:user_receive_packet/1
2024-07-16 07:44:51.636389+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook c2s_filter_send: mod_client_state:filter_chat_states/1
2024-07-16 07:44:51.636906+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook c2s_filter_send: mod_client_state:filter_pep/1
2024-07-16 07:44:51.637397+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook c2s_filter_send: mod_client_state:filter_presence/1
2024-07-16 07:44:51.637813+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply/4:315 Running hook c2s_filter_send: mod_client_state:filter_other/1
2024-07-16 07:44:51.638253+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@mod_client_state:filter_other/1:314 Won't add stanza for admin@abc.com/54781444652829145323347 to CSI queue
2024-07-16 07:44:51.638667+00:00 [debug] <0.1756.0>@mod_client_state:dequeue_sender/2:365 Flushing packets of admin@abc.com from CSI queue of admin@abc.com/54781444652829145323347
2024-07-16 07:44:51.639257+00:00 [notice] <0.1756.0> (websocket|<0.1755.0>) Send XML on stream = <<"<iq xml:lang='en' to='admin@abc.com/54781444652829145323347' from='admin@abc.com' type='error' id='register1'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'><username>riddhi</username><password>riddhi123</password></query><error type='auth'><forbidden xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/><text xml:lang='en' xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>Access denied by service policy</text></error></iq>">>



Access denied by service policy

You didn't specifu how you installed ejabberd, what version you installed, if you modified its default configuration, and what configuration are you using right now.
And that is relevant, because the server is telling that account was registration was denied because of the service policy, which is probably determined by the server configuration.
For example, if you installed ejabberd from the binary installers or container images provided by ProcessOne, account registration using IBR is allowed. But some operating system packagers disable that feature by default in their configuration file.

we are using ejabberd version 23.10 and using the debian 11 operating system, we have installed ejabberd which has provided by process-one. By using below :
Link:
https://www.process-one.net/downloads/downloads-action.php?file=/23.10/ejabberd_23.10-1_amd64.deb" -O ejabberd_23.10-1_amd64.deb

Your configuration file says:
acl:
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      
access_rules:
  trusted_network:
    deny: loopback
    allow: all
  register:
    allow: all  # Allow registration for all users and connections (including s2s)

modules:
  mod_register:
    ip_access: trusted_network  # Ensure trusted network is used for registration
    access: register  # Use the newly defined access rule

Your configuration says: deny registrations from loopback clients (clients that connect from localhost, from 127.0.0.1), and allow external clients (clients that connect from other machines).
Are you connecting to this server from the same machine? What does ejabberd.log say?

We are trying to connect from outside from the server by using rest api, I have added ejabberd.log.

Are you running your code from a separate computer?

Yes, i am using code from separate server

Also i have tried by removing deny: loopback from access_rule, but not worked
